# Vue.JS functions in different instances

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm new to VUE and can't figure how to solve my issue.

I have:

```
<div id="myapp">
   <select v-model="selected" @change="onChange();onChangeChart()">
</div>
```

Where I call my vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#myapp'
})
```

When I change the select the method onChange loads a table. Which works fine.

Now, inside the same page I want to add a chart. I'm using Vue Google Charts ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-charts#usage ).

I've added inside the main #myapp div, vue root this element:

```
<div id="chartapp"></div>
```

And in js I have:

```
let dataChart =  
new Vue({
  el: "#chartapp",
  template:
    '<GChart type="ColumnChart" :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions"/>',
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: [],
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          subtitle: "Sales"
        }
      }
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
      this.onChangeChart()
  },
  methods: {
        onChangeChart() {
          axios
              .get('/API')
              .then(response => {
                chartData = response.data
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              })
        }
    },
});
```

I'm getting several errors in my console.

[image]

Can't figure how to have two instances or call a function from one vue instance to another.

The objective is to when changing the selected option to load the table and also the chart with the corresponding data.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As the error said, the function `onChangeChart()` doesn't exists. This is because the function is called in one instance  `#myapp` and declared in another `#chartapp`.

Move that select to the template of #chartapp instance and the error will go, but I don't think that's what you want. Check the [docs for vue components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) you will have a lot of problems if you continue with the idea of puting vue instances inside one another, it will be better if you start thinking in multiple components instead of multiple instances.

The best at this moment for your case, is to have the main instance with the select and to have a `component` rendering the chart, there are different ways on how you can make your component react to a change from outside. For example: you could hear the change on the select (as you already do) with a callback function; and from that function you can call a method inside the component, you could also emit a global event after the change and the component could hear that event or you could be using props and the component react to any change.

**Note:** If you are new to vue, you could be using [Vue3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-overview.html) instead of Vue2, since you are starting you could use that as an advantage.

Answer (score -1):

its complaining that onChangeChart() is not a known function. This is how I do an axios call:

```
created(){
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos')
.then(response => {
this.myDataHolder = response.data[3];
console.log(response)
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
},
```

Where this is placed after the method:{},

Comment: The question is not related to axios and I think this example could be missleading.